# CI/CD for Azure Data Factory - Cannot publish in the collaboration branch

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-data-factory

We are working in the customer Azure tenant as members and integrated DevOps GIT to the ADF resource.

We have successfully created and merged the changes to the collaboration branch but have not been able to publish from there to the adf_publish repo as we get the following error:

> "The client "*value*" with the id Object "*value*" is not authorized
>   to perform the action "...Microsoft.Resources / deployments / write" on
>   the scope "...
>   /providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/publishing_1585587726090"
>   or the scope is invalid. If access has been granted recently, update
>   the credentials."

What could be the problem? I am already in the collaboration branch (master).

**The configuration of our accounts are:**

**Data factory role:** Data Factory contributor

**DevOps role:** Contributor

**Data factory GIT repo security configuration:**
[repo security configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNUmt.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to be Data Factory Contributor at the resource group level.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that worked!. What if there is more than one Data Factory in the Resource Group? That person could publish in the master of all ADFs?

Comment: Yes, that person could publish in all ADFs of the resource group. That is why you need to have one resource group by ADF.